# Are Web Audio APIs viable for scheduling non-audio events?

Tags: browser, web-audio-api

Say I want something to happen after exactly 30 seconds. I've seen people claim that Web Audio can be used to achieve this due to its accurate timers. But I've never seen an example of how this could be achieved. Also, if you use `AudioContext` for this, how do you avoid the limitation of being able to initialize `AudioContext` only after a user gesture?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, the answer is no. The Web Audio API allows you to precisely schedule events on the audio thread. But if you want to use that ability to schedule something on the main thread you need to send a message back from the audio thread to the main thread. The timing of that message is then as imprecise as any other timing mechanism on the main thread itself. Maybe it's a bit more or a bit less accurate but it's probably not dramatically different.